# How can I mount a SMB share exactly like Nautilus does it?

Tags: mount, nautilus, samba

I have an...interesting problem.  You see, I have a SMB share on a network that I would like to mount locally.  When I use Nautilus to mount it, everything works perfectly.  However, I need to configure the system to run without a GUI, meaning that I can't use Nautilus and instead must create an `fstab` entry or something similar.

However, when I try to mount the share using the following `fstab` entry:

```
//ip.address.goes.here/sharename /path/to/mountpoint cifs  username=user,password=pass,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

The share *mounts*, but the permissions are seriously messed up and prevent me from doing anything.

I *know* that the share can be mounted properly, as Nautilus does it.  My question is, *how* does Nautilus do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nautilus uses the Gnome Virtual File System (gvfs) to mount devices. In a system that's already running a gvfsd daemon you can initiate a mount manually using the `gvfs-mount` command e.g.

```
gvfs-mount smb://ip.address.goes.here/sharename
```

which should cause a link to the share to appear in the Nautilus sidebar; the actual mountpoint should appear in the filesystem at `/run/user/<UID>/gvfs` (or `$HOME/.gvfs` on earlier versions).

I'm not sure that will be an option in a truly headless environment: I suggest you create a [new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) detailing your exact issues with the `fstab` method.

Comment: I learned something today!  Edit and upvote!  ;-)

Comment: gvfs-mount did not exist in Ubuntu 21.10. I searched the web and found that now the command is `gio mount smb://server.address/path/to`.